# Generating a random string based on previous string

Tags: php

Okay so I'm trying to make a system where I can call:

```
echo _stringClamp("string");
```

it pushes "string" & the random string(needs to be a new random string each refresh) to an array, and if I call it twice

```
echo _stringClamp("string");
echo _stringClamp("string");
```

it will echo the same value.
This is what I have so far.

```
<?php
function _stringClamp ($string){

$stringSave = $string;

$stringChars = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890";

$strings = array();

$string = str_shuffle($string);

$string = "__" . $string;

$id = end($strings);

    for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {

        $string.= $stringChars[rand(0, strlen($stringChars) - 1)];

    }

$strings[$stringSave] = $stringSave;

if (in_array($stringSave, $strings)) {

    return $strings[$string];

}else{

    $strings[$stringSave] = $string;
    print_r($strings);

}

}

echo _stringClamp("IDs");
echo "<br>";
echo _stringClamp("IDs");


?>
```

Comment: How would a new "random" string be the "same"? That is sort of the opposite of random...

Comment: on refresh id=817289387198389, if I call id again echo 817289387198389 however if I refresh id=7826867382 and if I call id again echo 7826867382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get what you are asking for you would probably need to have a random value generated before you call the function then use that random value as a second parameter such as:

```
<?php

$num = rand(0, 100000);

echo _stringClamp("string", $num);
echo _stringClamp("string", $num);

?>
```

This would provide a random number to use in your function but if you refresh the page the number will change.  However if called twice on the same page it would have the same output value.... Right?

You could even use a randomly generated string instead of a number...

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you need to use [hash-functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) (guarantee same output for same input).

Comment: but on refresh the hash is the same, it needs to change on refresh.

Comment: concatenate it with time, for example, or another auto-changing value

Answer (score 0):

Just hash the current time.

```
$Seed = time();
$RandomString = md5($Seed);
```

If you don't want to string to be predictable (eg knowing when the script ran could let someone predict the string) then use a random number generator...

```
$Seed = rand();
$RandomString = md5($Seed);
```

As long as the variable is declared somewhere outside the function...

```
$RandomString = md5(time());

function _stringClamp($String) {
    global $RandomString;
    return $String . $RandomString;    
}
```

You should get the same string every time

Comment: Would $randomstring be out of scope? As its not parsed to the function, nor is it global?